# What happens in the long run?

Tags: combinatorics, dynamical-systems, markov-chains

Suppose we have a round table with 4 boys, each having a bowl with cereals. There is an adult in the same room. When the adult leaves the room, the boys start stealing each other's cereal, but they can $\textbf{only}$ steal from its neighbor as they $\textbf{cannot}$ leave their seat. When the adult comes back, they stop stealing each other's cereal.

${\bf question:}$ If the adult leaves and comes back $N$ times, can we say about the number of cereals in each boy's bowl? Are they eventually all have the same number of cereals?

${\bf thought}:$ We can start by letting $x_i$ be the number of cereal in ith bowl. So, initially we can encode our situation in a vector ${\bf x} = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$. After the adult leaves the room, now $x_1$ becomes $x_1 + k_1 x_2 + k_2 x_4$ ;
$x_2$ becomes $x_2 + k_3 x_1 + k_4 x_3$; $x_3$ becomes $x_3 + k_5 x_2 + k_6 x_4$ and $x_4$ becomes $x_4 + k_7 x_3 + k_8 x_1$, so after one step we obtain new vector

$$ {\bf y }  = \left( \begin{matrix}  x_1 + k_1 x_2 + k_2 x_4 \\ x_2 + k_3x_1 + k_4 x_3 \\  x_3 + k_5 x_2 + k_6 x_4 \\ x_4 + k_7 x_3 + k_8 x_1 \end{matrix} \right) = \underbrace{ \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & k_1 & 0 & k_2 \\ k_3 & 1 & k_4 & 0 \\ 0 & k_5 & 1 & k_6 \\ k_8 & 0 & k_7 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) }_{A} {\bf x}$$

So, in order to solve this problem, we may have to compute $A^N {\bf x}$ which seems pretty laborious.

Is this a correct approach to the problem?

${\bf Update:}$
Let us assume that at each round, each boy takes half the number of cereals from the neighbor. In this case, then

$$ {\bf y} = \left( \begin{matrix} (x_2+x_4)/2 \\ (x_1+x_3)/2 \\ (x_2+x_4)/2 \\ (x_1+x_3)/2 \end{matrix} \right) $$

Comment: The parity of $(x_1+x_3)-(x_2+x_4)$ is an invariant.

Comment: Can one cereal move multiple times before the adult returns?

Comment: $k_i$ can’t be both positive. So there may have a moment $t$ that a boy $j$ has nothing in his bowl and is not stolen at $t+1$, hence the matrix formula cant be applied in this case

Comment: I've added the "combinatorics" tag; I'm not sure if this is really a combinatorics problem, but I couldn't think of anything that fits the question better. if anyone has an alternative idea please feel free to replace the tag (+1)

Comment: -1 This is extremely unclear. Is the number of cereals in each bowl an integer at all times? Because your matrix representation of the numbers of cereals over time will eventually fail to produce integers for almost all values of $x_i$ and $k_i$. Does each boy steal the same number (or proportion) each time the adult leaves? This is not made explicit in the question, but is implicit in your matrix representation of the problem. And in any interpretation of the problem it is clear that the boys will not necessarily eventually have the same number of cereals. So what is there to 'solve'?

Comment: There are too many problems with this question. 1) you don't say if the amounts are discrete or continuous; 2) you don't say if the amounts stolen are limited or not; 3) you seem to say that a boy has a single neighbor (?); 4) what difference does it make the the adult comes out and in several times, as the stealing seems to be a continuous activity. I am shocked to see so many upvotes to such a buggy question.

Comment: The bounty is very unfortunate, as this question needs *extensive* rewording (and probably rethinking) to be appropriate for this site.

Comment: Independently of my above complaints, your matrix approach assumes that 1) the coefficients $k$ are constant, 2) the stealings are made as fractions of the available amounts, and that does not seem to be implied by the problem statement.

Comment: See my updates.

Comment: When properly written, this is a relatively simple problem of a transition matrix that is a probability matrix (every row adds up to $1$), and so the eventual behavior is dominated by the eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues with absolute value $1$. But it needs to be properly written out.

Comment: Note that your “thought” seems to neglect to take into account that some of the boys cereal will be lost to his neighbors. So the new total for $x_1$ is not $x_1+k_1x_2+k_2x_4$, you must adjust this by subtracting $k_3x_1$ and $k_8x_1$ (which is what kids 2 and 4 take away from him).

Comment: In my update, see that I took into account that so that $x_1$ becomes $(x_2+x_4)/2$ after one step.

Comment: Yes, but you didn’t fix the rest. You just said “Okay, let’s do this special case...”

Comment: @ILoveMath If you are already familiar with eigenvalues and eigenvectors, ArturoMagidin has already solved the problem and someone just needs to write up the solution.  The transition matrix has eigenvalues of $\pm 1$ (with multiplicity 1) and 0 (with multiplicity 2).  You just need to write the initial condition ($x$) in terms of those eigenvectors and then calculating $A^N x$ is extremely easy.  On the other hand, if you are not familiar with eigenvalues and eigenvectors, there is probably no solution that you would understand without learning more linear algebra.

Comment: The matrix should have $1-k_3-k_8$, $1-k_1-k_5$, etc. on the diagonals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special case is fairly straightforward with the theory of probability matrices (matrices with nonnegative entries, all of whose columns add up to $1$). You have a transition matrix that is
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0
\end{array}\right).$$
Because every column adds up to $1$, this is a probability matrix; all eigenvalues $\lambda$ satisfy $|\lambda|\leq 1$, $1$ is definitely an eigenvalue, and the long-term behavior is dominated by the eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues of absolute value $1$.

Here, the matrix clearly has rank $2$, so the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$: the nullspace has basis $\mathbf{v}_3=(1,0,-1,0)^t$ and $\mathbf{v}_4=(0,1,0,-1)^t$.

The eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ has eigenvector $(1,1,1,1)^t$, which we will want to normalize (make the entries add up to $1$) to the eigenvector $\mathbf{v}_1=(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4})^t$. And the fourth eigenvalue in this case is $\lambda=-1$, which has corresponding eigenvector $\mathbf{v}_2=(1,-1,1,-1)^t$.

If $\mathbf{x}_0$ is the initial distribution, then we can express $\mathbf{x}_0$ in terms of the basis $\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_4$. If we have
$$\mathbf{x}_0 = \alpha_1\mathbf{v}_1 + \alpha_2\mathbf{v}_2 + \alpha_3\mathbf{v}_3 + \alpha_4\mathbf{v}_4,$$
then after applying $A$ to $\mathbf{x}_0$ $n$ times you will get
$$A^n\mathbf{x}_0 = \alpha_1\mathbf{v}_1 + (-1)^N\alpha_2\mathbf{v}_2.$$
Now, because the entries of $\mathbf{v}_0$ add up to $1$ and the entries of $\mathbf{v}_2$ add up to zero, we see that $\alpha_1$ is just the total amount of cereal we started with.

The summand $(-1)^N\alpha_2$ makes this a bit tricky (it’s easier when you have an odd number of kids, because then you don’t get an eigenvalue $-1$). A way to simplify the analysis is to replace the basis $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2$ of the image with
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{w}_1 &= \mathbf{v}_1 + \frac{1}{4}\mathbf{v}_2 = \left(\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2},0\right)^t\\
\mathbf{w}_2 &= \mathbf{v}_1 - \frac{1}{4}\mathbf{v}_2 = \
\left(0,\frac{1}{2},0\frac{1}{2}\right)^t.
\end{align*}$$
Then the action of $A$ is to swap $\mathbf{w}_1$ and $\mathbf{w}_2$.

So if we have an initial cereal distribution of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, then after $N$ steps, you will have:

1. If $N$ is odd, then each of kids 1 and 3 have the average amount of cereal that kids 2 and 4 had (that is, half the sum of their totals), while kids 2 and 4 will have the average amount that kids 1 and 3 had.
2. If $N$ is even, then each of kids 1 and 3 has the average amount of cereal that kids 1 and 3 had to start with, and kids 2 and 4 will have half the average amount of cereal that kids 2 and 4 had to start with.

Basically, after the first step, you are just swapping cereal amounts between adjacent kids; you could just shuffly the bowls clockwise at each step and get the right distribution.

(If there were five kids, each taking half from its neighbor, then the limiting process has each kid with one fifth the total amount of cereal served. More generally, if you have $K$ kids, if $K$ is odd then at the limit they all have the same amount, and if $K$ is even, then you divide the cereal into that served to odd kids and that served to even kids, and eventually you will be swapping the averages of each half between the kids)

For the general case you will have something similar: every column will add up to $1$ so you still have a probability matrix, so the long-term behavior is dominated by the eigenvalue $1$ (and possibly $-1$, if it is an eigenvalue). The eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues different from $1$ all will have entries that add up to $0$, so the coefficient of the eigenvector corresponding to $1$ (once normalized) is just the sum of the entries of the initial condition. That multiple of the eigenvector of $1$ is the limiting behavior. So all you need to do is (1) determine if $-1$ is an eigenvalue; and (2) find the eigenvectors corresponding to $1$ (and if necessary to $-1$).

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the stealings, made and suffered, when summed over the period of teacher's absence might turn out to be proportional to the starting amounts on which they are perpetrated.
Then for the guy in e.g. position $2$ we will have the following incoming and outgoing flux

[image: boys_cereals_1]

That is
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  \Delta x_{\,1}  = k_{\,1,\,2} x_{\,2}  + k_{\,1,\,4} x_{\,4}
  - \left( {k_{\,2,\,1}  + k_{\,4,\,1} } \right)x_{\,1}  \hfill \cr 
  \Delta x_{\,2}  = k_{\,2,\,1} x_{\,1}  + k_{\,2,\,3} x_{\,3}
  - \left( {k_{\,1,\,2}  + k_{\,3,\,2} } \right)x_{\,2}  \hfill \cr 
  \Delta x_{\,3}  = k_{\,3,\,2} x_{\,2}  + k_{\,3,\,4} x_{\,4}
  - \left( {k_{\,2,\,3}  + k_{\,4,\,3} } \right)x_{\,3}  \hfill \cr 
  \Delta x_{\,4}  = k_{\,4,\,1} x_{\,1}  + k_{\,4,\,3} x_{\,3}
  - \left( {k_{\,1,\,4}  + k_{\,3,\,4} } \right)x_{\,4}  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
where the factors will presumably be non-negative (no donations).
We shall also assume that the out-flux at each step will not be such as to leave the affetcted cup empty, independently from the in-flux.
So it is a reasonable model that the factors, at least those in parenthesis,  will lay in the range $0 \le k_{\, n\, m} \le 1/2$.
It is also assumed that the cereals, between the various mutual stealings, are not eaten, so that the total quantity
remains fixed, and the sum of the net incomings is null.

In matricial notation
$$
\left( {\matrix{ {\Delta x_{\,1} }  \cr {\Delta x_{\,2} }  \cr {\Delta x_{\,3} }  \cr {\Delta x_{\,4} }  \cr } } \right)
 = \left( {\matrix{
   { - \left( {k_{\,2,\,1}  + k_{\,4,\,1} } \right)} & {k_{\,1,\,2} } & 0 & {k_{\,1,\,4} }  \cr 
   {k_{\,2,\,1} } & { - \left( {k_{\,1,\,2}  + k_{\,3,\,2} } \right)} & {k_{\,2,\,3} } & 0  \cr 
   0 & {k_{\,3,\,2} } & { - \left( {k_{\,2,\,3}  + k_{\,4,\,3} } \right)} & {k_{\,3,\,4} }  \cr 
   {k_{\,4,\,1} } & 0 & {k_{\,4,\,3} } & { - \left( {k_{\,1,\,4}  + k_{\,3,\,4} } \right)}  \cr 
 } } \right)
\left( {\matrix{{x_{\,1} }  \cr {x_{\,2} } \cr {x_{\,3} }  \cr {x_{\,4} }  \cr  } } \right)
$$
i.e.
$$
\Delta {\bf x} = {\bf M}\,{\bf x}
$$

Designating the unit vector and its transpose as
$$
{\bf u} = \left( {\matrix{ 1  \cr  1  \cr  1  \cr   1  \cr } } \right)
\quad \overline {\bf u}
  = \left( {1,1,1,1} \right)
$$
we have infact
$$
\overline {\bf u} \;{\bf M} = {\bf 0}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \overline {\bf u} \;\Delta {\bf x}
 = \Delta \left( {\overline {\bf u} \;{\bf x}} \right) = \Delta N = 0
$$
So $\bf M$ has determinant null, and it has rank $3$ in general:  for instance the minor in the upper left corner
has determinant
$$
\left| {{\bf M}_3 } \right| =  - k_{\,1,\,2} k_{\,4,\,1} \left( {k_{\,2,\,3}  + k_{\,4,\,3} } \right)
 - k_{\,3,\,2} k_{\,4,\,3} \left( {k_{\,2,\,1}  + k_{\,4,\,1} } \right)
$$
The rank will be lower than $3$ for particular values of the $k$'s.

If the rank is $3$ then the null-space of $\bf H$ has dimension $1$.
At equilibrium we shall have
$$
\Delta {\bf x}_\infty   = 0\quad
  \Rightarrow \quad {\bf x}_\infty   \in {\rm null - space}\left( {\bf M} \right)
$$
as well as that the total of the bowls content shall remain constant
$$
\overline {\bf u} \;{\bf x}_\infty   = \overline {\bf u} \;{\bf x}_0 
$$
We can then solve the homogeneous system to get
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
{\bf x}_\infty   = \lambda \;\left( {\matrix{
   {k_{\,1,\,2} k_{\,2,\,3} \left( {k_{\,1,\,4}  + k_{\,3,\,4} } \right)
 + k_{\,1,\,4} k_{\,4,\,3} \left( {k_{\,1,\,2}  + k_{\,3,\,2} } \right)}  \cr 
   {k_{\,2,\,1} k_{\,3,\,2} \left( {k_{\,1,\,4}  + k_{\,3,\,4} } \right)
 + k_{\,4,\,1} k_{\,3,\,4} \left( {k_{\,1,\,2}  + k_{\,3,\,2} } \right)}  \cr 
   {k_{\,2,\,1} k_{\,1,\,4} \left( {k_{\,2,\,3}  + k_{\,4,\,3} } \right)
 + k_{\,2,\,3} k_{\,3,\,4} \left( {k_{\,2,\,1}  + k_{\,4,\,1} } \right)}  \cr 
   {k_{\,1,\,2} k_{\,4,\,1} \left( {k_{\,2,\,3}  + k_{\,4,\,3} } \right)
 + k_{\,3,\,2} k_{\,4,\,3} \left( {k_{\,2,\,1}  + k_{\,4,\,1} } \right)}  \cr 
 } } \right)
}$$
with $\lambda$ being the constant that provides the above normalization.

Then in the example in which the "rapacities" are unbiased , i.e. when $k_{1,2} = k_{1,4} = k_1$ and so on, we have
$$
{\bf M} = \left( {\matrix{
   { - \left( {k_{\,2}  + k_{\,\,4} } \right)} & {k_{\,1} } & 0 & {k_{\,1} }  \cr 
   {k_{\,2} } & { - \left( {k_{\,1}  + k_{\,3} } \right)} & {k_{\,2} } & 0  \cr 
   0 & {k_{\,3} } & { - \left( {k_{\,2}  + k_{\,\,4} } \right)} & {k_{\,3} }  \cr 
   {k_{\,\,4} } & 0 & {k_{\,\,4} } & { - \left( {k_{\,1}  + k_{\,3} } \right)}  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
and
$$
{{{\bf x}_\infty  } \over {\overline {\bf u} \;{\bf x}_0 }}
 = {1 \over {k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + k_{\,3}  + k_{\,\,4} }}\;
\left( {\matrix{{k_{\,1} }  \cr{k_{\,2} }  \cr{k_{\,3} }  \cr{k_{\,\,4} }  \cr } } \right)
$$
which means that the contents of the bowls will tend to stabilize in proportion to the rapacities
independently from the starting point.

But for the sequence of the  ${\bf x}_n$ to actually converge to ${\bf x}_\infty$ we need that
$$
{\bf x}_n  = \left( {{\bf I} + {\bf M}} \right)^{\,{\bf n}} {\bf x}_0 \; \to \;{\bf x}_\infty
  \quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad \left( {{\bf I} + {\bf M}} \right)^{\,{\bf n}} \; \to \;{\bf L}
$$
the sequence $\left( {{\bf I} + {\bf M}} \right)^{\,{\bf n}}$ be also convergent.
For that,  it is necessary that the matrix in question has a preminent eigen-value, so that
its reiterated application will bring the ${\bf x}_n$ towards the corresponding eigen-vector.
That is clear once the matrix is diagonalized.

And since the null-vector of $\bf M$ is an
eigenvector with $\lambda = 1$ of $\left( {{\bf I} + {\bf M}} \right)$, then for the convergence
the other three eigen-values shall have a lower absolute value .

If $\left( {{\bf I} + {\bf M}} \right)^{\,{\bf n}} $ diverges, since we cannot have  quantities negative nor
higher than the starting total amount, ${\bf x}_n$ will perennially oscillate.

The eigen-values are the roots of a fourth degree polynomial, so a general expression is quite involute.
But considering that the vectors ${\bf x}_n$ move over the diagonal (hyper)plane $\overline {\bf u} \;{\bf x}_n /\overline {\bf u} \;{\bf x}_0  = 1$,
then we can tell that a necessary condition for the convergence is that the matrix $\left( {{\bf I} + {\bf M}} \right)$ brings a vector from the border of the plane to the interior of it.
This is the assumption that $0 < k_{n,m} < 1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

In the special case, notice that each boy doesn't keep any of his orignal cereal - it gets shared evenly between his two neighbours. So even if boy 1 and boy 3 initially have different amounts, boys 2 and 4 each have $\frac{x_1+x_3}{2}$ cereal after 1 round, and boys 1 and 3 each have $\frac{x_2+x_4}{2}$ cereal after 1 round. After that, the cereal amounts keep alternating - after an even number of rounds, boys 1 and 3 have $\frac{x_1+x_3}{2}$ and boys 2 and 4 have $\frac{x_2+x_4}{2}$, and after an odd number of rounds, boys 1 and 3 have $\frac{x_2+x_4}{2}$ cereal and boys 2 and 4 have $\frac{x_1+x_3}{2}$.